# Step Function Mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, get, aws-step-functions

**Use Case:** I would like to map over an array of SKUs in the JSON received, do a `GET` request with the SKU, obtain the `product_id` from that request, and re-create the array, replacing the SKUs (in order) with their respective `product_id`.

**Step Function Steps:**

1. Input Code is received
2. Map Task -> `GET` Request -> ??
3. New Object created with `product_id`
4. New Object is used for business use case

**Input Code Example:**

```
{
  "data": {
      "product": {
          "configurable_product_links": [
              "SKU1",
              "SKU2",
              "SKU3",
              "SKU4"
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

**Output Code Example:**

```
{
  "data": {
      "product": {
          "configurable_product_links": [
              "product_id_1",
              "product_id_2",
              "product_id_3",
              "product_id_4"
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

I will be using a Call Back Return Pattern with the step function for queuing requests into the API I obtain the `product_id`s from.

Comment: Have you tried the example(s) in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html ?

Comment: The part I'm struggling with conceptually is understanding how to push the new array back into the JSON.

Comment: If you look at the `"Validate All"` snippet: by using the `ResultPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Map state can handle this use case.  The [ItemProcessor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html#itemprocessor) field would specify a Lambda task to perform the lookup.  The output will be an array of results.  The results array preserves the order of the input `ItemsPath` array.

Although Map iterations receive a single input value by default, you can pass arbitrary inputs to each iteration.  Map States have an [ItemSelector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html#itemselector) property, which *"overrides the values of the input array items before they're passed on to each Map state iteration."*  You have access to the `$$` [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map) and the `$` input object.

```json
"ItemSelector": {
        "Index.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
        "Value.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
        "Secret.$": "$.previousTask.secret",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When mapping through an array in Step Functions, it does not allow one to access previous task information, outside of the Map.

When doing a `GET` Request, credentials are required, and it is bad practise to hard-code them. For AWS, the secret manager can be used.

Thus, the soltion to this issue has been solved by [Iterating a Loop Using Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html#create-iterate-pattern-step-1).

We'll count the quantity of elements in the array, and loop through until the end. This removes the limitations of the map task, whilst still achieving the requirements.

Comment: Why do you need to "access previous task information"?  The `Map` state will scatter-gather your requests.  It outputs an array of results that retains the original input order.

Comment: I need to get the secrets from Secrets Manager, and make a `HTTP` `POST` request for each mapped item. I required doing it once at the top before the loop (to be more efficient).